# Alias's in the Attribute Table's Column Preview/Column Filters

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, alias

We've spent some time setting up alias's in Layers/Properties.../Fields (Fig. 1) for database fields displayed as the column headers in the Attribute Table (Fig. 2).

Switching the layout in the Attribute Table from table view to form view and selecting between the Column Preview, the column names are now no longer aliased (Fig. 3). (This is also the case for the Column Filters, but is not shown here)

Is there any way to get the filters to use the aliased names? If there is a PyQGIS solution I'd be happy to hear about it.

[image: Alias's]

[image: AttribTable]

[image: FormView]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible right now (without reimplementing the whole form view in python). Please open a [feature request](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues), consider creating a pull request or funding somebody to implement this.